# ODBC API query parameters

Tags: c++, c, database, odbc

Suppose I have a query `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary < :salary_limit` that should be executed thru ODBC. Using ODBC API, I can get, for example, the number of parameters in my query (`SQLNumParams`), but how do I get parameter names?

Answer (score -1):

there are no parameter name. ODBC Parameters are always typed as '?' thus referenced by index.

Comment: No actually ODBC allows for binding parameters by name if the driver supports it.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/binding-parameters-by-name-named-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16